# The fastest way to save graph to file in C

Tags: c, file, graph

I have such a problem: I need to save a large graph with > million edges to txt file. Each edge is represented with a structure containing 3 integers: from, to, cost. My task is to write a program that will fastly save the whole graph to txt file in such format: "from to cost\n".

I am interested in the method, how to do that.
My idea is in creating a huge buffer of chars, where I add each digit to the buffer without the need to reverse then (first of all I get the number of digits of each integer, then add each digit to the buffer, then I add whitespace/new line symbol and do it until the last number is added.

Then I save the whole buffer to file by using fwrite() function.

Despite the fact that this method is relatively fast, I saw programs that do it faster. My question is: do you know more efficient way to implement this program in order to get faster results?

The program must be in C language.

```
typedef struct {
   int edge_start; 
   int edge_count; 
   int parent; 
   int cost; 
} node_t;

typedef struct {
   graph_t *graph;
   node_t *nodes;
   int num_nodes; 
   int start_node; 
} dijkstra_t;
```

The function to get the number of digits:

```
int getNumberOfDigitsBig(int x) {
  if (x >= 10000) {
        if (x >= 10000000) {
            if (x >= 100000000) {
                if (x >= 1000000000)
                    return 9;
                return 8;
            }
            return 7;
        }
        if (x >= 100000) {
            if (x >= 1000000)
                return 6;
            return 5;
        }
        return 4;
    }
    if (x >= 100) {
        if (x >= 1000)
            return 3;
        return 2;
    }
    if (x >= 10)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Save function:

```
    const dijkstra_t *const dij = (dijkstra_t*)dijkstra;

    if (dij) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (f) {

    int numberOfNodes = dij->num_nodes;
    long bufferLength = numberOfNodes * (9 * 3 + 3);
    buffer = (char *)malloc(bufferLength + 1);
    long bufferCounter = 0;

    int number;
    // printf("i = %d\n", number);
    int counter;
    int digits;

    buffer[bufferCounter++] = '0';
    buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';
    buffer[bufferCounter++] = '0';
    buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';
    buffer[bufferCounter++] = '-';
    buffer[bufferCounter++] = '1';
    buffer[bufferCounter++] = '\n';

    for(int i = 1; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
        const node_t *const node = &(dij->nodes[i]);

        number = i;

         digits = getNumberOfDigits(number);
         counter = bufferCounter;

         do {
           buffer[counter + digits] = ZERO + number % 10;
           --digits;
           ++bufferCounter;
         } while(number /= 10);

       buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';

       number = node->cost;

       if(number != -1) {

         digits = getNumberOfDigitsBig(number);

         counter = bufferCounter;
         do {
           buffer[counter + digits] = ZERO + number % 10;
           digits = digits - 1;
           bufferCounter = bufferCounter + 1;
         } while(number /= 10);
       } else {
         buffer[bufferCounter++] = '-';
         buffer[bufferCounter++] = '1';

       } 

      buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';

        buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';

        number = node->parent;

        if(number != -1) {

            digits = getNumberOfDigitsBig(number);

            counter = bufferCounter;
            do {
                buffer[counter + digits] = ZERO + number % 10;
                --digits;
                ++bufferCounter;
            } while(number /= 10);
        } else {
              buffer[bufferCounter++] = '-';
              buffer[bufferCounter++] = '1';

        }

        buffer[bufferCounter++] = '\n';

    }

  fwrite(buffer, 1, bufferCounter, f);

  ret = fclose(f) == 0;
  free(buffer);
  }
 }
```

Thanks for attention.

Comment: Why do you prepare the buffer in memory? I/O functions are already buffered, just stream out one line after the other and you won't even need to allocate a huge buffer (of an unknown size). However without your actual code is hard to say where it may be improved.

Comment: Please [edit] your qquestion explain what this is: _...txt file in such format: " \n"_. Also show the definition of the structure and the code you've written, otherwise it's hard to say anything about your code.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Nebril you can write `[mcve]` in the comment, this will expand automatically to this: [mcve].

Comment: @MichaelWalz  Where is that useful tidbit about `[mcve]` documented?

Comment: @chux: funny that you ask, I had the same experience. It's actually [in the Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)!

Comment: @MichaelWalz corrected the question

Comment: @AntonKretov Curious, 1) why `long` in `long bufferLength = ...`.  Why not `int`, `unsigned`, others? 2) Suggest `size_t`  3) `numberOfNodes * (9 * 3 + 3)` is done using `int` math.  Assigning that to a `long` does not prevent overflow.  4) Code should use `size_t num_nodes; ...  size_t numberOfNodes` and `size_t bufferLength = numberOfNodes * (9 * 3 + 3);`

Comment: As you do your own buffering, you can use `setbuf(f, NULL);`  right after `fopen`, which switches off the usage of the internal buffer used by `fwrite` and thus avoiding copying your buffer into the internal buffer used by `fwrite`. This might speed  up your program a bit.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I've recently tried your suggestion and it actually gave a bit of speed to all this stuff. But not as much as I would like to. But the idea is fine

Comment: I would try the suggestion of the very first comment as alternative. A buffer of limited size may even have positive effects over a huge buffer containing the complete file at once before writing. And, please, don't forget to make your benchmarking with optimized release compiles. (Otherwise the results are not valuable.) My last idea: memory mapped files are mentioned usually when such questions appear...

Comment: Try using naively `fprintf` (no `setbuf(f, NULL)` in that case). This will also greatly simplify your code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz with fprinf() the whole thing works 1.5x-2x slower.

Comment: Not directly related, but in the `for` loop you should double check that `bufferLength` us never greater than `bufferCounter`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you need is an optimized version of printf that only processes positive integers. I did not benchmark it, but I would try to do as little comparisons and operations as possible, so I ended with that function:

```
int printint(FILE *fd, int n) {
    char buffer[32];     // an uint64_t uses max 20 chars in base 10 
    int i = sizeof(buffer);
    do {
        buffer[--i] = '0' + n%10;   // write digits from the right of buffer
        n /= 10;
    } while(n > 0);
    return fwrite(buffer + i, 1, sizeof(buffer) - i, fd);
}
```

Then I would not use a huge buffer, but just rely on the default buffering of a FILE *

Saving code could then become (more or less just started with the example form the question):

```
    const dijkstra_t *const dij = (dijkstra_t*)dijkstra;

    if (dij) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (f) {

    int numberOfNodes = dij->num_nodes;

    fputs("0 0 -1\n", f);

    for(int i = 1; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
        const node_t *const node = &(dij->nodes[i]);

        fputc(' ', f);

        number = node->parent;
        //printf("parent = %d\n", number);
        if(number != -1) {
            printint(number, f);
        } else {
              fwrite("-1", 1, 2, f);

        }

        fputc('\n', f);

    }

  ret = fclose(f) == 0;
  free(buffer);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but your solution had 1.5x longer save time than mine...

Comment: printf gets a string as an agrument, then makes a lot of formatting operations and returns string. It is far slower than my approach (3x-4x times slower).

Answer (score 0):

You can improve a little by using this "itoa":

```
void gwf_i2a(char *d, int i, int l) {
  char *e = d + l;
  while (l > 0) {
    e--;
    l--;
    e[0] = '0' + (i % 10);
    i /= 10;
  }
}
```

---

ORIGINAL TIME: 76 clicks (7.6e-05 seconds).

NEW      TIME: 39 clicks (3.9e-05 seconds).

---

source:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

#define ZERO '0'

void gwf_i2a(char *d, int i, int l) {
  char *e = d + l;
  while (l > 0) {
    e--;
    l--;
    e[0] = '0' + (i % 10);
    i /= 10;
  }
}

typedef struct {
  int x, y, z;
} graph_t;

typedef struct {
  int edge_start;
  int edge_count;
  int parent;
  int cost;
} node_t;

typedef struct {
  graph_t *graph;
  node_t *nodes;
  int num_nodes;
  int start_node;
} dijkstra_t;

graph_t graph = {111, 222, 3456789};
node_t nodes[] = {{1, 1, 1, 9999}, {2, 2, 2, 8999}, {2, 2, 2, 1234567890}};
dijkstra_t data[] = {&graph, (node_t *)&nodes, 4, 0};

int getNumberOfDigits(int x) {
  if (x >= 100) {
    if (x >= 1000) return 3;
    return 2;
  }
  if (x >= 10) return 1;
  return 0;
}

int getNumberOfDigitsBig(int x) {
  if (x >= 10000) {
    if (x >= 10000000) {
      if (x >= 100000000) {
        if (x >= 1000000000) return 9;
        return 8;
      }
      return 7;
    }
    if (x >= 100000) {
      if (x >= 1000000) return 6;
      return 5;
    }
    return 4;
  }
  if (x >= 100) {
    if (x >= 1000) return 3;
    return 2;
  }
  if (x >= 10) return 1;
  return 0;
}

void save(const char *filename, const dijkstra_t *dijkstra) {
  int ret;
  const dijkstra_t *const dij = (dijkstra_t *)dijkstra;
  char *buffer;
  if (dij) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (f) {
      int numberOfNodes = dij->num_nodes;
      long bufferLength = numberOfNodes * (9 * 3 + 3);
      buffer = (char *)malloc(bufferLength + 1);
      long bufferCounter = 0;

      int number;
      // printf("i = %d\n", number);
      int counter;
      int digits;

      buffer[bufferCounter++] = '0';
      buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';
      buffer[bufferCounter++] = '0';
      buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';
      buffer[bufferCounter++] = '-';
      buffer[bufferCounter++] = '1';
      buffer[bufferCounter++] = '\n';

      for (int i = 1; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
        const node_t *const node = &(dij->nodes[i]);

        number = i;

        digits = getNumberOfDigits(number);
        counter = bufferCounter;

        do {
          buffer[counter + digits] = ZERO + number % 10;
          --digits;
          ++bufferCounter;
        } while (number /= 10);

        buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';

        number = node->cost;

        if (number != -1) {
          digits = getNumberOfDigitsBig(number);

          counter = bufferCounter;
          do {
            buffer[counter + digits] = ZERO + number % 10;
            digits = digits - 1;
            bufferCounter = bufferCounter + 1;
          } while (number /= 10);
        } else {
          buffer[bufferCounter++] = '-';
          buffer[bufferCounter++] = '1';
        }

        buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';

        buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';

        number = node->parent;

        if (number != -1) {
          digits = getNumberOfDigitsBig(number);

          counter = bufferCounter;
          do {
            buffer[counter + digits] = ZERO + number % 10;
            --digits;
            ++bufferCounter;
          } while (number /= 10);
        } else {
          buffer[bufferCounter++] = '-';
          buffer[bufferCounter++] = '1';
        }

        buffer[bufferCounter++] = '\n';
      }

      fwrite(buffer, 1, bufferCounter, f);

      ret = fclose(f) == 0;
      free(buffer);
    }
  }
}

void new_save(const char *filename, const dijkstra_t *dijkstra) {
  int ret;
  const dijkstra_t *const dij = (dijkstra_t *)dijkstra;
  char *buffer;
  if (dij) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (f) {
      int numberOfNodes = dij->num_nodes;
      long bufferLength = numberOfNodes * (9 * 3 + 3);
      buffer = (char *)malloc(bufferLength + 1);
      long bufferCounter = 0;

      int number;
      int counter;
      int digits;

      buffer[bufferCounter++] = '0';
      buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';
      buffer[bufferCounter++] = '0';
      buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';
      buffer[bufferCounter++] = '-';
      buffer[bufferCounter++] = '1';
      buffer[bufferCounter++] = '\n';

      for (int i = 1; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
        const node_t *const node = &(dij->nodes[i]);
        int len = getNumberOfDigits(i) + 1;

        gwf_i2a((char *)&buffer[bufferCounter], i, len);
        bufferCounter += len;
        buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';

        number = node->cost;

        if (number != -1) {
          len = getNumberOfDigitsBig(number) + 1;
          gwf_i2a((char *)&buffer[bufferCounter], number, len);
          bufferCounter += len;

        } else {
          buffer[bufferCounter++] = '-';
          buffer[bufferCounter++] = '1';
        }

        buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';

        buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';

        number = node->parent;

        if (number != -1) {
          digits = getNumberOfDigitsBig(number);

          counter = bufferCounter;
          do {
            buffer[counter + digits] = ZERO + number % 10;
            --digits;
            ++bufferCounter;
          } while (number /= 10);
        } else {
          buffer[bufferCounter++] = '-';
          buffer[bufferCounter++] = '1';
        }

        buffer[bufferCounter++] = '\n';
      }

      fwrite(buffer, 1, bufferCounter, f);

      ret = fclose(f) == 0;
      free(buffer);
    }
  }
}
void original() {
  clock_t t;
  t = clock();
  save("bogus.txt", data);
  t = clock() - t;
  std::cout << "original: " << t << " clicks (" << ((float)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
            << " seconds)." << std::endl;
}
void new_test() {
  clock_t t;
  t = clock();
  new_save("new_bogus.txt", data);
  t = clock() - t;
  std::cout << "NEW: " << t << " clicks (" << ((float)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
            << " seconds)." << std::endl;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  original();
  new_test();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion has made a kind of improvement, I would say, it became 5-10% faster on small graphs (< 1000000 edges) and 20-30% faster on bigger graphs (> 1000000 edges). I wonder if there is any additional kind of improvements that can be done in order to improve the code.
Btw, maybe you could suggest me some kind of reading this file with edges? I have it fast enough, but it could be faster. I can show my code

Comment: The only thing I can think is pre-process your array to avoid memory cache-miss if the node and graph are too far away in memory, but this could be difficult as the improvement is not guaranteed in all cases.

Comment: also, I think is a good idea to build a more complete example of what you need (a working example) with a random data generator for us to test.

Comment: This is generator's code - https://paste.ofcode.org/sBFeT3EU657WT8EsPWSU26
I consider retyping all integers that do not accept negative values to uint32_t. I has to help too

Answer (score 0):

[Rewritten on 2018-01-13.]
Standard I/O (`printf()` etc.) is indeed comparatively slow in converting numerical data to text form. Here, the problem is to output lines of form

> *<node>* *<cost>* *<parent>*

where all three are either unsigned (32-bit) integers in decimal notation, or -1. For simplicity, let's reserve the value `UINT32_MAX` (4294967295) for `-1`.

I suggest a two-fold approach:

1. Construct each record from right to left. This avoids the need of checking how many digits there are in a number.
2. Buffer a number of records at once. This reduces the number of `fwrite()` calls, at the cost of a modest dynamically allocated buffer.

   Note that this means that the records in each chunk must be processed last-to-first, in order to retain the correct order.

Consider the following code.  Note that I've reduced the definitions of `node_t` and `dijkstra_t` to the fields that area actually used, so that the following example can be compiled as-is. Also note that instead of `-1` for `parent` or `cost`, one must use `UINT32_MAX`, as their types are now `uint32_t`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t    parent;     /* Use UINT32_MAX for -1 */
    uint32_t    cost;       /* Use UINT32_MAX for -1 */
} node_t;

typedef struct {
    node_t     *nodes;
    uint32_t    num_nodes;
} dijkstra_t;

/* This function will store an unsigned 32-bit value
   in decimal form, ending at 'end'.
   UINT32_MAX will be written as "-1", however.
   Returns a pointer to the start of the value.
*/
static inline char *prepend_value(char *end, uint32_t value)
{
    if (value == UINT32_MAX) {
        *(--end) = '1';
        *(--end) = '-';
    } else {
        do {
            *(--end) = '0' + (value % 10u);
            value /= 10u;
        } while (value);
    }
    return end;
}

/* Each record consists of three unsigned 32-bit integers,
   each at most 10 characters, with spaces in between
   and a newline at end. Thus, at most 33 characters. */
#define  RECORD_MAXLEN  33
/* We process records in chunks of 16384.
   Maximum number of records (nodes) is 2**32 - 2 - RECORD_CHUNK,
   or 4,294,950,910 in this case. */
#define  RECORD_CHUNK   16384
/* Each chunk of record is up to CHUNK_CHARS long.
   (Roughly half a megabyte in this case.) */
#define  CHUNK_CHARS   (RECORD_MAXLEN * RECORD_CHUNK)

/* Save the edges in a graph to a stream.
   Returns 0 if success, -1 if an error occurs.
*/
int save_edges(dijkstra_t *dij, FILE *out)
{
    if (dij && out && !ferror(out)) {
        const int       nodes = dij->num_nodes;
        const node_t   *node  = dij->nodes;

        const uint32_t  root_parent = dij->nodes->parent;
        const uint32_t  root_cost   = dij->nodes->cost;

        char           *buf, *end, *ptr;
        uint32_t        o;

        /* Allocate memory for the chunk buffer. */
        buf = malloc(CHUNK_CHARS);
        if (!buf)
            return -1;

        end = buf + CHUNK_CHARS;

        /* Temporarily, we reset the root node parent
           to UINT32_MAX and cost to 0, so that the
           very first record in the output is "0 0 -1". */
        dij->nodes->cost   = 0;
        dij->nodes->parent = UINT32_MAX;

        for (o = 0; o < nodes; o += RECORD_CHUNK) {
            uint32_t  i = (o + RECORD_CHUNK < nodes) ? o + RECORD_CHUNK : nodes;

            /* Fill buffer back-to-front. */
            ptr = end;
            while (i-->o) {
                const node_t  *curr = node + i;

                /* Format: <i> ' ' <cost> ' ' <parent> '\n' */
                /* We construct the record from right to left. */

                *(--ptr) = '\n';
                ptr = prepend_value(ptr, curr->parent);
                *(--ptr) = ' ';
                ptr = prepend_value(ptr, curr->cost);
                *(--ptr) = ' ';
                ptr = prepend_value(ptr, i);
            }

            /* Write the chunk buffer out. */
            if (fwrite(ptr, 1, (size_t)(end - ptr), out) != (size_t)(end - ptr)) {
                dij->nodes->cost = root_cost;
                dij->nodes->parent = root_parent;
                free(buf);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        /* Reset root node, and free the buffer. */
        dij->nodes->cost = root_cost;
        dij->nodes->parent = root_parent;
        free(buf);

        /* Check for write errors. */
        if (fflush(out))
            return -1;
        if (ferror(out))
            return -1;

        /* Success. */
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Additional speedup is possible, if we can use POSIX low-level I/O ([`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [`close()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html), [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), and [`fstat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) from `<unistd.h>`). When the destination is a pipe or device, we can just directly write the data; when the destination is a file, we should write in chunks of multiples of `st_blksize`, to avoid read-modify-write cycles. Unlike standard I/O, with low-level I/O we can do that with just one "overflow" buffer of `st_blksize`, without having to copy the entire chunk buffer around in memory.  However, since the question is not tagged [posix](/questions/tagged/posix), I shall refrain from further discussion along those edges.

---

OP stated their own version is still faster. I found that difficult to believe, because it does much more work than my version above. When I checked, on my machine a large dataset (of say 100,000,000) cannot be written in a single `fwrite()` call, as it only does a partial write; a loop is required to actually write the entire dataset. Therefore, in my opinion, the benchmark OP uses to compare the different version is very suspect.

Consider the following microbenchmark instead. It generates a singly linked list, and uses an externally compiled `save_graph()` function to output it (to standard output). There are three versions implemented: *null*, which does not save anything at all; *antonkretov*, for OP's implementation (adapted to work here); and *nominalanimal*, for mine.

**Makefile**:

```
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -std=c99 -O2 -Wall
LDFLAGS :=
BINS    := test-null test-antonkretov test-nominalanimal
NODES   := 100000000

.PHONY: all clean run

all: clean $(BINS)

clean:
        rm -f $(BINS) *.o

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^


test-null: main.o data-null.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

test-antonkretov: main.o data-antonkretov.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

test-nominalanimal: main.o data-nominalanimal.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

run: $(BINS)
        @echo "Testing $(NODES) nodes."
        @./test-null $(NODES) > /dev/null

        @echo "Overhead (nothing saved):"
        @bash -c 'time ./test-null $(NODES) > /dev/null'
        @echo ""

        @echo "Anton Kretov:"
        @bash -c 'time ./test-antonkretov $(NODES) > /dev/null'
        @echo ""

        @echo "Nominal Animal:"
        @bash -c 'time ./test-nominalanimal $(NODES) > /dev/null'
        @echo ""
```

Note that this forum converts <kbd>Tab</kbd>s to spaces, and Makefile format requires the indentation to use spaces, so if you copy and paste the above to file, you need to run e.g. `sed -e 's|^  *|\t|' -i Makefile` to fix it.

**data.h**:

```
#ifndef   DATA_H
#define   DATA_H
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define  INVALID_COST    UINT32_MAX
#define  INVALID_PARENT  UINT32_MAX

typedef struct {
    uint32_t    parent;     /* Use INVALID_PARENT for -1 */
    uint32_t    cost;       /* Use INVALID_COST for -1 */
} node_t;

typedef struct {
    node_t     *nodes;
    uint32_t    num_nodes;
} dijkstra_t;

int save_graph(dijkstra_t *, FILE *);

#endif /* DATA_H */
```

**data-null.c**, for measuring runtime overhead:

```
#include "data.h"

int save_graph(dijkstra_t *dij, FILE *out)
{
    /* Does not do anything */
    return 0;
}
```

**data-antonkretov.c**, version of OP's save routine, for comparison:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "data.h"

int getNumberOfDigits(uint32_t x)
{
    if (x >= 10000) {
        if (x >= 10000000) {
            if (x >= 100000000) {
                if (x >= 1000000000)
                    return 9;
                return 8;
            }
            return 7;
        }
        if (x >= 100000) {
            if (x >= 1000000)
                return 6;
            return 5;
        }
        return 4;
    }
    if (x >= 100) {
        if (x >= 1000)
            return 3;
        return 2;
    }
    if (x >= 10)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int save_graph(dijkstra_t *dij, FILE *out)
{
    uint32_t    numberOfNodes = dij->num_nodes;
    size_t      bufferLength = numberOfNodes * (size_t)33;
    size_t      bufferCounter = 0, counter;
    size_t      bytes;
    uint32_t    number, digits, i;
    char       *buffer;

    if ((size_t)(bufferLength / 33) != numberOfNodes)
        return -1;

    buffer = malloc(bufferLength);
    if (!buffer)
        return -1;

    buffer[bufferCounter++] = '0';
    buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';
    buffer[bufferCounter++] = '0';
    buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';
    buffer[bufferCounter++] = '-';
    buffer[bufferCounter++] = '1';
    buffer[bufferCounter++] = '\n';

    for (i = 1; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
        const node_t *const node = dij->nodes + i;

        number = i;
        digits = getNumberOfDigits(number);
        counter = bufferCounter;
        do {
            buffer[counter + digits] = '0' + (number % 10u);
            --digits;
            ++bufferCounter;
        } while (number /= 10u);

        buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';

        number = node->cost;
        if (number != UINT32_MAX) {
            digits = getNumberOfDigits(number);
            counter = bufferCounter;
            do {
                buffer[counter + digits] = '0' + (number % 10u);
                --digits;
                ++bufferCounter;
            } while (number /= 10u);
        } else {
            buffer[bufferCounter++] = '-';
            buffer[bufferCounter++] = '1';
        }

        buffer[bufferCounter++] = ' ';

        number = node->parent;
        if (number != UINT32_MAX) {
            digits = getNumberOfDigits(number);
            counter = bufferCounter;
            do {
                buffer[counter + digits] = '0' + (number % 10u);
                --digits;
                ++bufferCounter;
            } while (number /= 10u);
        } else {
            buffer[bufferCounter++] = '-';
            buffer[bufferCounter++] = '1';
        }

        buffer[bufferCounter++] = '\n';
    }

    counter = 0;
    while (counter < bufferCounter) {
        bytes = fwrite(buffer + counter, 1, bufferCounter - counter, out);
        if (!bytes) {
            free(buffer);
            return -1;
        }
        counter += bytes;
    }

    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

**data-nominalanimal.c**, my chunked back-to-front version of the save routine:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "data.h"

/* This function will store an unsigned 32-bit value
   in decimal form, ending at 'end'.
   UINT32_MAX will be written as "-1", however.
   Returns a pointer to the start of the value.
*/
static inline char *prepend_value(char *end, uint32_t value)
{
    if (value == UINT32_MAX) {
        *(--end) = '1';
        *(--end) = '-';
    } else {
        do {
            *(--end) = '0' + (value % 10u);
            value /= 10u;
        } while (value);
    }
    return end;
}

/* Each record consists of three unsigned 32-bit integers,
   each at most 10 characters, with spaces in between
   and a newline at end. Thus, at most 33 characters. */
#define  RECORD_MAXLEN  33
/* We process records in chunks of 16384.
   Maximum number of records (nodes) is 2**32 - 2 - RECORD_CHUNK,
   or 4,294,950,910 in this case. */
#define  RECORD_CHUNK   16384
/* Each chunk of record is up to CHUNK_CHARS long.
   (Roughly half a megabyte in this case.) */
#define  CHUNK_CHARS   (RECORD_MAXLEN * RECORD_CHUNK)

/* Save the edges in a graph to a stream.
   Returns 0 if success, -1 if an error occurs.
*/
int save_graph(dijkstra_t *dij, FILE *out)
{
    if (dij && out && !ferror(out)) {
        const int       nodes = dij->num_nodes;
        const node_t   *node  = dij->nodes;

        const uint32_t  root_parent = dij->nodes->parent;
        const uint32_t  root_cost   = dij->nodes->cost;

        char           *buf, *end, *ptr;
        uint32_t        o;

        /* Allocate memory for the chunk buffer. */
        buf = malloc(CHUNK_CHARS);
        if (!buf)
            return -1;

        end = buf + CHUNK_CHARS;

        /* Temporarily, we reset the root node parent
           to UINT32_MAX and cost to 0, so that the
           very first record in the output is "0 0 -1". */
        dij->nodes->cost   = 0;
        dij->nodes->parent = UINT32_MAX;

        for (o = 0; o < nodes; o += RECORD_CHUNK) {
            uint32_t  i = (o + RECORD_CHUNK < nodes) ? o + RECORD_CHUNK : nodes;

            /* Fill buffer back-to-front. */
            ptr = end;
            while (i-->o) {
                const node_t  *curr = node + i;

                /* Format: <i> ' ' <cost> ' ' <parent> '\n' */
                /* We construct the record from right to left. */
                *(--ptr) = '\n';
                ptr = prepend_value(ptr, curr->parent);
                *(--ptr) = ' ';
                ptr = prepend_value(ptr, curr->cost);
                *(--ptr) = ' ';
                ptr = prepend_value(ptr, i);
            }

            /* Write buffer. */
            if (fwrite(ptr, 1, (size_t)(end - ptr), out) != (size_t)(end - ptr)) {
                dij->nodes->cost = root_cost;
                dij->nodes->parent = root_parent;
                free(buf);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        /* Reset root node, and free the buffer. */
        dij->nodes->cost = root_cost;
        dij->nodes->parent = root_parent;
        free(buf);

        if (fflush(out))
            return -1;
        if (ferror(out))
            return -1;

        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

and finally the main program itself, **main.c**, that generates the data and calls the `save_graph()` functions:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "data.h"

#define  EDGES_MAX  4294901759

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    dijkstra_t graph;
    size_t     bytes;
    uint32_t   edges, i;
    char       dummy;

    if (argc != 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: %s EDGES\n\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    if (sscanf(argv[1], " %" SCNu32 " %c", &edges, &dummy) != 1 || edges < 1 || edges > EDGES_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid number of edges.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    bytes = (1 + (size_t)edges) * sizeof graph.nodes[0];
    if ((size_t)(bytes / (1 + (size_t)edges)) != sizeof graph.nodes[0]) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Too many edges.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    graph.num_nodes = edges + 1;
    graph.nodes = malloc(bytes);
    if (!graph.nodes) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Too many edges: out of memory.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Generate a graph; no randomness, to keep timing steady. */
    graph.nodes[0].parent = INVALID_COST;
    graph.nodes[0].cost = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= edges; i++) {
        graph.nodes[i].parent = i - 1;
        graph.nodes[i].cost = 1 + (i % 10);
    }

    /* Print graph. */
    if (save_graph(&graph, stdout)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Write error!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Done. */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Running `make clean run` (or `make NODES=100000000 clean run`) recompiles the benchmarks, and measures their run time, for a graph with 100,000,000 nodes. On my machine, the output is

```
Testing 100000000 nodes.
Overhead (nothing saved):

real0m0.514s
user0m0.297s
sys0m0.217s

Anton Kretov:

real0m4.059s
user0m3.379s
sys0m0.680s

Nominal Animal:

real0m3.336s
user0m3.151s
sys0m0.184s
```

which shows that mine is significantly faster. If we ignore the overhead (of generating the graph), mine took about 2.8 seconds of real time to save the data to `/dev/null`, whereas OP's took about 3.5 seconds. In other words, mine shows a 20% speed improvement.

It is important to note that both tests do produce the exact same output. For example, both `./test-nominalanimal 100000000 | sha256sum -` and `./test-antonkretov 100000000 | sha256sum -` show the exact same SHA256 checksums, `7504a1c97167701297c03c4aab8b0f20c5cac82a50128074d6e09c474353d0f8`.
(You can also save the output to a file, and compare them; both are exactly  1,987,777,795 bytes long, and contain the exact same data. I did check.)

If you want to run a benchmark that stores the data to storage, for the comparisons to be fair, you need to start with cold caches. Otherwise the order in which you run the benchmarks will heavily impact their timings.

Comment: Actually I don't generate any graph. The only thing I get is txt file with all the edges. My task is to find all the shortest paths from the first node to others. Then I have to save my shortest paths to txt file. Hence, bunkry files are not the option.

Comment: I have just commented your comment. I couldn't understand your reply, because you were definitely writing about smth else. Why did you comment rand()? I don't use it at all. As I've said: the only thing I have to implement is fast saving. I just get the structure with millions of edges and I have to save them to .txt file. You then wrote about binary files (I don't understand as well, why) that I'm not allowed to use. I've run your save code (output_edge() function) and it produced much slower performace. I presume you commented the code of graph creator, but I don't generate graph at all

Comment: @AntonKretov: Now I understand. I saw your original post, then your comment referring to your generator at paste.ofcode.org, and not the edits to your question in between. (I don't know why, probably connection issues.) Yes, there are many ways to speed up both saving and loading of such graphs in ASCII text form. I'll rewrite my answer to do only the save, using the structures shown now in your question.

Comment: I get segmentation fault while executing your function. After the last prepend_value() it throws such an error

Comment: I managed to edit your code in order to make it work (the error was in assigning a pointer to the first element in buf to end, you had to point to the last one. But my approach is still faster than yours.

Comment: @AntonKretov: I don't believe you. Care to post your benchmark? Note that the way you only issue one `fwrite()` call, and do not check its return value, you are likely to not be able to write very large arrays at all, because for example Linux limits each single write (and thus `fwrite()`) to 2<sup>32</sup>-1 bytes or so. I suspect that your test does not even write all the data to disk, and therefore shows results too good to be true.

Comment: @AntonKretov: Indeed, my own microbenchmark (included above) shows that mine is at least 20% faster (2.8 seconds versus 3.5 seconds to save a graph of 100,000,000 nodes/edges). (For a million nodes/edges, the times are 0.03 seconds versus 0.02 seconds.)